# Hint - Find a basis for $U=$ {$p \in P_4(R) : p(6)=0$}

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $P_4(R)$ denote the set of all polynomials of at-most degree $4$. I was attempting to find a basis of $U=$ {$p \in P_4(R) : p(6)=0$}. I do not want a solution, but just a hint as to where to look. The following was my approach.

Because $p(6)$ must equal $0$. We know that the polynomial will have a factorisation such as $(x-6)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. Multiplying throughout this polynomial, we see that at the end there is always a multiple of $6$. Hence, the basis would consist of the number 6. But because this polynomial can have degree: 1, 2, 3, 4. We would also have to add the vectors
$x, x^2, x^3, x^4$(Abuse of notation here, what I mean is that they are all function. $f_j(x)=x^j$).

So, the basis would consists of $6, x, x^2, x^3, x^4$. We might be able to change this basis up a bit. We want that $a_0(6)+a_1(6)+a_2(6)^2+a_3(6)^3+a_4(6)^4=0$.

At this point I am stuck. Because in the next question, it asks to extend this basis to a basis of $P_4(R)$. But this basis would also be a basis of $P_4(R)$, as any linearly independent list of the right length is a basis of that vector space.

Could someone give any hints as to what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply out,  you get $x^4-(6+a+b+c)x^3+(6a+6b+6c+ab+ac+bc)x^2-(6ab+6bc+6ac+abc)x+6abc$.

In the standard basis,  $\{x^4,x^3,x^2,x,1\}$, that's the vector $(1,-(6+a+b+c),6a+6b+6c+ab+ac+bc,-(6ab+6bc+6ac+abc),6abc)$.

Now choose $a,b,c=0$ and get $(1,-6,0,0,0)$.  Next choose $a=1,b=c=0$ to get $(1,-7,6,0,0)$.  Let $a=1,b=1,c=0$, get $(1,-7,13,-6,0)$.  And $a=b=c=1$ for $(1,-9,21,-19,6)$.

This gives one basis.   Notice there are $4$ basis vectors,  so the dimension is $4$.

---

Now to extend,  notice that there's no way,  with this basis,  to get a nonzero constant polynomial (or, any polynomial that isn't zero at $6$, for that matter).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Never thought of thinking about it in terms on the standard basis.

Comment: I did have another question. How do we know to stop when we have 4 vectors in our basis. We can deduce that from the rank nullity theorem, but without using that, how would we know to stop at 4 vectors?

Comment: Well,  I knew it would probably be $4$, because,  each equation,  in this case $p(6)=0$, tends to knock it down by one.   Also,  the fact that there's four degrees of freedom, $a,b,c,d$  tips you off.  And you know it's not $5$, because then it would be everything.   Cheers.

Comment: Oops I miscounted.  Forget the second argument:   there's only $a,b,c$.  The polynomial doesn't need to be monic though (lead coefficient $1$).  So there's your $d$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $p\in U\leq\textbf{P}_{4}(\mathbb{R})$, it can be written as $p(x) = a + bx + cx^{2} + dx^{3} + ex^{4}$. Hence we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
p(6) = 0 & \Rightarrow a + 6b + 36c + 196d + 1296e = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow a = -(6b + 36c + 196d + 1296e)
\end{align*}

Now you can express the elements of $U$ in terms of four parameters.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yeah I can work out from here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Seeker you are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Define $T: P_4(\Bbb{R})\to \Bbb{R}$ by

$$T_6(p) =p(6) $$ $\forall p\in P_4(\Bbb{R})$

Then

1. $T_6$ is a linear map .
2. $T_6$ is surjective.
3. $\ker T_6=\{p  \in  P_4(\Bbb{R}): p(6)=0\}$

Then by Rank -Nullity theorem,

$\dim(\ker(T_6)) =\dim(P_4(\Bbb{R})) -\dim(R(T_6)) =5-1=4$

Comment: That is  also a good approach. Thanks a lot!